# How to setup wlan0 in Nerves

Tags: raspberry-pi, elixir, nerves-project

I created a new [Elixir Nerves](https://github.com/nerves-project/nerves) project and try to connect my Raspberry Pi Zero W to the local wifi.

In my `target.exs`, I set the following config:

```
config :nerves_network,
  regulatory_domain: "US"

config :nerves_network, :default,
  wlan0: [
    networks: [
      [
        ssid: "wifi_ssid_here",
        psk: "my_password_here",
        key_mgmt: String.to_atom("WPA2-EAP-CCMP")
      ]
    ]
  ]

config :nerves_init_gadget,
  ifname: "wlan0",
  address_method: :dhcp,
  mdns_domain: "nerves.local",
  node_name: node_name,
  node_host: :mdns_domain
```

If I burn or push this config to my Raspberry Pi Zero W, it does boot, but I am unable to connect to it with e.g. `ssh nerves.local` or by going to `http://nerves.local`.

Does somebody know how to properly configure the Pi so that it connects to the wifi and is accessible under `nerves.local`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the authentication protocol `WPA2-EAP-CCMP` of the network. It usually requires an email + password combination, which I could not provide using `nerves_network`. I switched to a `WPA2-PSK` network, which only requires a password and it worked.